# Android: NDK setup in windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, augmented-reality

I've been planned to develop an Augmented_Reality(AR) application in an android. So I've gone through various of contribution installing a libraries in eclipse(IDE) like artool,qcar sdk and so on, then I've found that NDK installation should be made before getting into artool kit or qcar sdk So I started to install NDK and progressed as they said in below link:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

after doing 'Cygwin' installation they wrote to write 'make -v' in console. Hhen I did I got 'GNU make 3.82.90' but theirs is 'GNU make3.81' as:

[image: image 1]

where it wasn't as same mine. I know that am using updated cygwin but my problem is I can't able to get .so file as they mentioned accordingly in eclipse. So could you tell me, where I made junk and how can I recover to run AR application in eclipse. Thank you!

Comment: In this case make version doesn't matter, it is really minor difference. What exactly happens when you run ndk-build? Any output messages/errors? Is .so file created under libs folder?

Comment: yeah I did and executed the application from my phone but gotta 'force to close' error but I didn't got any error while debugging.

Comment: This my exact problem while building ndk 

http://i.imgur.com/akmDG.png

Comment: Verify that you have make.exe in cygwin folder and you are running it from there, not some other make.exe from some folder in PATH.

Comment: I'm sure of it.. am running same exe file. even I tried from cygwin folder (make.exe).. getting same response. one-thing am not sure about the 2nd issue(like define gnumake environment written as)

"To solve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:

     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make

3. Call 'ndk-build' again. "

  export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make" 
what does it represent?

Comment: also what does "export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make" mean it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are installing cygwin (I used a wizard) make sure you open the DEVEL tree and install MAKE (binary is fine, no need for source).

I also get all the GCC and MINGW stuff just in case.

Perhaps uninstall cygwin, and reinstall using the wizard and ensure  MAKE is selected from DEVEL tree.

Comment: I've did but same response as below,

"To solve the issue, follow these steps: 1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed. NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later! 2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in: export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make 3. Call 'ndk-build' again. "

Answer (score 1):

actually if you are using window then you do not need to install cygwin. you can also run your project with cmd prompt with following command

start>cmd>cd C:\demoworkspace\testingndk>enter

in Command prompt This is my directory where my project is located with project name. after this
run the ndk address like
C:\demoworkspace\testingndk>C:\ndk-path\ndk-build

ndk-path is directory name where your ndk is located. this will automatically pick your jni c file.
for ndk related query please write me at kdeepak5477@gmail.com